# Explore contents of connected mobile device

Tags: c++, qt

In my Windows project, I need to read/write off a mobile device (Android phone for example) when it's connected via USB as an MTP device.

I tried using `QDir::drives` but that only returns the HDD and USB devices on the user's machine. `C:/ D:/ E:/` etc.

How would I get the drive path of a connected MTP device such as the portable device shown in this screenshot? The device name is not known at the time.

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you can browse the content of the device, simply go into a folder on the device and then check the path in the explorer bar - this should give you an answer. Maybe something like ``\\A0001\foo\bar\baz.txt``

Comment: Thanks but I'm wanting to know how to do this programmatically. I want my program to give me a list of all the devices connected so then I can scrub through and scan the contents for a valid match.

Comment: MTP devices are not drives.

Comment: Simple internet search for open source mtp libraries: http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ah... well that would explain it. Thanks :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd388998(v=vs.85).aspx You can also try to use the apis shown in this link.

Comment: @BitTickler Yep just found this a min ago. Thanks :)